# Can I parse xpath using python, selenium and lxml?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, lxml, xpath

So I have been trying to figure our how to use BeautifulSoup and did a quick search and found lxml can parse the xpath of an html page. I would LOVE if I could do that but the tutorial isnt that intuitive.

I know how to use Firebug to grab the xpath and was curious if anyone has use lxml and can explain how I can use it to parse specific xpath's, and print them.. say 5 per line..or if it's even possible?!

Selenium is using Chrome and loads the page properly, just need help moving forward.

Thanks!

Comment: What is bs4? Wikipedia says its some sedan :)

Comment: @Himanshu Sorry- bs4 = beautifulsoup4

Comment: Okay. To use xpath on xml docs with python, see element tree http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support . You may not be able to parse all html docs right off the web as they may not be all valid xml docs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285990/parse-html-via-xpath

Answer (score 1):

`lxml`'s ElementTree has a .xpath() method    (note that the ElementTree in the `xml` package in the Python distribution dosent have that!)

e.g.

```
# see http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

from lxml import etree

# root = etree.parse('/tmp/stack-overflow-questions.xml')
root = etree.XML('''
        <answers>
            <answer author="dlam" question-id="13965403">AAA</answer>
        </answers>
''')

all_answers = root.xpath('.//answer')

for i, answer in enumerate(all_answers):
    who_answered = answer.attrib['author']
    question_id = answer.attrib['question-id']
    answer_text = answer.text
    print 'Answer #{0} by {1}: {2}'.format(i, who_answered, answer_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `lxml`. Because the efficiency of `lxml` is more higher than `selenium` for large elements extraction. You can use `selenium` to get source of webpages and parse the source with `lxml`'s xpath instead of the native `find_elements_with_xpath` in `selenium`.