# find some value in javascript, in the response form

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests, robobrowser

I have an url `www.example.com/test`
so by using robobrowsker to visit this url, I find some js in response and it contains something like this

```
var token = _.unescape("&lt;input name=&quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;wi5U8xXijdXRrPR4aG84OAjSLsuS1YqTV4X7VLDnWeuwr72D39H-KXBsyG7eZEZPT7YXW7GF26IiQBrW0vcEZd5Bqrjof_CVEUFRTDPS4rx68Opmi6juZXnGDEtb9nsBXxM4Why2WNlflqFM6purXw2&quot; /&gt;");
    aw.antiforgeryToken[$(token).attr('name')] = $(token).val();
```

I want to get '`wi5U8xXijdXRrPR4aG84OAjSLsuS1YqTV4X7VLDnWeuwr72D39H-KXBsyG7eZEZPT7YXW7GF26IiQBrW0vcEZd5Bqrjof_CVEUFRTDPS4rx68Opmi6juZXnGDEtb9nsBXxM4Why2WNlflqFM6purXw2`'

I tried this

```
browser=RoboBrowser()
browser.open('https://www.example.com/test')
result=browser.find('script',{'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'})
```

This gives 'None'

so how can I do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`br.find` works on html, and as the stuff you want is inside a JS call so we can't use it.

so other options are

1. use rejex (wiz. a bit hardcoded in my opinion)

   By finding the parent node in which the node which eventually contains the data you want is present, and then find that string i.e.  `'wi5U8xXijdXRrPR4aG84OAjSLsuS1YqTV4X7VLDnWeuwr72D39H-KXBsyG7eZEZPT7YXW7GF26IiQBrW0vcEZd5Bqrjof_CVEUFRTDPS4rx68Opmi6juZXnGDEtb9nsBXxM4Why2WNlflqFM6purXw2'` via regex
2. lxml.html (xpath)
   it is other way which I MAY prefer is `lxml.html` or `import html from lxml` one and the same thing

here is a bit of representation of it.

```
data = lmxl.html(parsedData)
stuff = data.xpath('XPATH to you data')
```

you can find more here [Can I parse xpath using python, selenium and lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965403/can-i-parse-xpath-using-python-selenium-and-lxml]) and have a look in [docs](http://lxml.de/) 
as well

I hope I was helpful.

cheers.