# Finding the first table in a HTML file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I am trying to find the first `table` in a `HTML` file and copy everything of the `table`
to a string `s`

```
f = open('page.html' , 'r')
s = ""
for line in f.readlines():
  line = line.strip()
  if line.find('<table'):
    s += line
  if line.find('</table>'):
    break
print s
```

This code is not working.
How do I solve it using the standard python library?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @sshashank124: I have to use the standard python library

Comment: Your first line.find is missing a > after <table. However, your code still not give the expected output. You will only get the first line of the <table> in s. Also, what if you get an HTML document with everything on one line (no line breaks)? :)

Comment: @gurka It's not a bug, it's a feature :) It's needed for tags like `<table id=xyz>`.

Comment: @VeilEclipse did the solutions helped you? If does, how about accepting one? And if doesn't tell also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) maybe, see this SO question: [Parse HTML via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285990/parse-html-via-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to the standard library, then it's obvious that you need the contents between the first `<table>` and the last `</table>`.

To do this, you'll need a stack. Read the file from the beginning. Whenever you encounter a `<table>`, push its position on the stack, and whenever you see a `</table>`, pop one from the stack. This will ensure matching the `</table>`s with their corresponding `<table>`s.

Look out for the last `</table>` - if popping from the stack makes it empty, then it must close the first `<table>`, so store this position.

Now you have the positions of the first `<table>` and the last `</table>` - so you can copy all the contents between them to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` for this.

```
import re
tbl_pat = re.compile(r'<table(.*?)>(.*)</table>')
f = open('page.html' , 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    m = tbl_pat.match(line)
    if m:
        print m.group(2)
        break
```

Comment: It won't capture tags like `<table id=xyz>`.

Comment: well I did not got it first time. thank you for pointing out.