# Regex detection part of string

Tags: python, regex

How can I detect this part: `/table/LEKPOOZZZCV/LSK1633923` from string variable:

`'<a class="live-data__header" href="/table/LEKPOOZZZCV/LSK1633923"><div class="table_names" data-v-fc63c1b6=""><span class="table_names__name" data-v-fc63c1b6="" title="W............`

using regex expression?

Comment: `(?<=href=\")[^\"]+` but you should really use an xml/html parser and XPath the data you need.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a regex here?  I'd use an XML parser and then get the `href` attribute from the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat pls, can you send how you use XML parser, Im newbie in this field... have problems with this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/285990/2191572

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findall` such as

```
import re
s = '<a class="live-data__header" href="/table/LEKPOOZZZCV/LSK1633923"><div class=....'
print(re.findall('href="([^"]*)"', s))
```

in order to get as a `list` or

```
l = re.findall('href="([^"]*)"', s)
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

to get as a `string`

Comment: `href="([^"]*)"` retrieves too much if OP doesn't know how to access capture groups.